# Can I have a function replaces all of these functions?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I use an eventListener and getElementsByClass to create a function that does the same for these buttons instead of having a function for each one?
Any explanations will help, thank you!

```
     <button class = "Button" onclick = "Ginga()"><span id = "Ginga" class = "Movements" >ginga</span></button>
     <button class = "Button" onclick = "Base()"><span id = "Base" class = "Movements" >base</span></button>
     <button class = "Button" onclick = "Role()"><span id = "Role" class = "Movements" >role</span></button>
     <button class = "Button" onclick = "Negativa()"><span id = "Negativa" class = "Movements" >negativa</span></button>
    <div id = "SequenceContainer">
    <div id = "Sequence"></div>
    </div>

function Ginga() {
    var Ginga = document.getElementById('Ginga');
    var GingaCln = Ginga.cloneNode(true);
    Sequence.appendChild(GingaCln);
}
function Base() {
    var Base = document.getElementById('Base');
    var BaseCln = Base.cloneNode(true);
    Sequence.appendChild(BaseCln);
}
function Role() {
    var Role = document.getElementById('Role');
    var RoleCln = Role.cloneNode(true);
    Sequence.appendChild(RoleCln);
}
function Negativa(){
    var Negativa = document.getElementById('Negativa');
    var NegativaCln = Negativa.cloneNode(true);
    Sequence.appendChild(NegativaCln);
}
```

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212). You could use `data-*` attributes to store the target ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can.

Change the `onClick` event with:

```
onclick = "justOne(this)"
```

(`this` is used to send to the script the element that the user clicked on)

And replace the javascript with just one function:

```
function justOne(element) {
  Sequence.appendChild(element.children[0].cloneNode(true));
}
```

(we select the first child of the clicked element and clone it)

That's it!

LE: I've added another answer with a different approach, using `eventListener` and `getElementsByClassName`, as you asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <button class = "Button" onclick = "OneForAll()"><span id = "Ginga" class = "Movements" >ginga</span></button>
     <button class = "Button" onclick = "OneForAll()"><span id = "Base" class = "Movements" >base</span></button>
     <button class = "Button" onclick = "OneForAll()"><span id = "Role" class = "Movements" >role</span></button>
     <button class = "Button" onclick = "OneForAll()"><span id = "Negativa" class = "Movements" >negativa</span></button>
    <div id = "SequenceContainer">
    <div id = "Sequence"></div>
    </div>

function OneForAll(event) {
  var element = event.target;
  var elementCln = element.cloneNode(true);
  Sequence.appendChild(elementCln);
}
```

Comment: event.target already IS the element. You don't need to get its id and use getElementById()

Comment: I didn't understand your statement. Pardon.

Comment: lupz is basically saying `event.target === document.getElementById(event.target.id)`.  In other words, you're taking the node and then pulling out the id, so you can traverse the DOM to find the same node you already had.  It's a wasted process

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `eventListener` and `getElementsByClass` (as you asked) like this:

```
<button class = "Button"><span id = "Ginga" class = "Movements" >ginga</span> </button>
<button class = "Button"><span id = "Base" class = "Movements" >base</span></button>
<button class = "Button"><span id = "Role" class = "Movements" >role</span></button>
<button class = "Button"><span id = "Negativa" class = "Movements" >negativa</span> </button>
<div id = "SequenceContainer">
<div id = "Sequence"></div>
</div>

<script>
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("Button"), function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
        Sequence.appendChild(this.children[0].cloneNode(true));
    });
});
</script>
```

Please note that I have removed the 'onclick' event inside the `<button>` element, as it is no longer needed.

This method works like this:

1. We call the forEach method of the Array class, to iterate over an "array like" element: `[].forEach.call()`
2. The list of buttons is obtained using `document.getElementsByClassName("Button")`
3. We add an event listener to each button using the  `element.addEventListener` method;

Keep in mind that the script has to be inserted after the button definitions. If you insert the script in the `head` section, it will not work, because the script runs but the DOM in not yet defined (there are no buttons to attach events to).